# Create a Numpy array representing connections in a network

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have an array describing network links between nodes:

```
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  4.]])
```

This would be a linear 4 node network with links from node 1 to node 2 and so on..

What would be the best way to convert this information to an array of the following format?

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

The column numbers then represent the "to nodes" and the rows the "from nodes".

Another example would be:

```
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  4.]])
```

giving

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: `float` is probably not the best variable type to store node ids.

Comment: @eumiro Fair point, probably should use integer or bool, but this serves as an illustration of what I want.

Comment: 0-based node ids would make it a little simpler, too

Comment: @njzk2 True, although I'm stuck with 1-based due to source data - could make `-1` the first step though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node ids should be integers. Also the rows and columns in numpy are numbered from zero, so we have to substract one in each dimension:

```
import numpy as np

conns = np.array([[ 1,  2],
                  [ 2,  3],
                  [ 3,  4]])
net = np.zeros((conns.max(), conns.max()), dtype=int)

# two possibilities:

# if you need the number of connections:
for conn in conns:
    net[conn[0]-1, conn[1]-1] += 1

# if you just need a 1 for existing connection(s):
net[conns[:,0]-1, conns[:,1]-1] = 1
```

Comment: Instead of looping, couldn't you do `net[conns[:,0]-1, conns[:,1]-1] = 1`?